# How to parse typescript object with typed array(s) to xml including array object names

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript, libxml-js

I am trying to convert the `Person` Typescript object to XML, but it is not including the "CAR" tag inside the conversion, how can I achieve this?

Already tried with the libraries js2xmlparser and xml-js, working with Angular 8 and tried with JSON.Stringify() but the same result comes up in JSON, the Typescript array gets encoded without the name of the object it has nested inside.

```
export class Person {
  ...
  CarsList: Car[];

  constructor() {
    this.CarsList = [];
  }

}
```

```
export class Car {
  ...
  Parts: Parts[];
  Model: string;
  ...
}
```

The code that I am actually using to encode into xml is the following:

```
import * as xmlJs from 'xml-js';

// This is using the xml-js library to generate the xml in the return 
getWithXmlJsLibrary(obj: Person) {
   const options = { compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4 };
   return xmlJs.js2xml(obj, options);     // js2xml
  }
```

Expected result is

```
<Person>
    <CarsList>
       <Car>
         <Model>value</Model>
       </Car>
       <Car>
         <Model>value</Model>
       </Car>
       <Car>
         <Model>value</Model>
       </Car>
    </Carslist>
</Person>
```

But the actual result is

```
<Person>
    <CarsList>
         <Model>value</Model>
         <Model>value</Model>
         ...
    </Carslist>
</Person>
```